# How can i catch this error: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR: null value in column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

i am implementing test with rspec

i have this function params:

```
def update_section_params
        params.require(:section).permit(:type_id, :by_team)
end
```

i am using for update an section

```
if @section.update(update_treatment_params)
```

i am getting this error if by_team: nil

```
PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column
```

How can i catch that error in my test?

```
 payload = { by_team: nil }
 put ".../.../sections/#{@section1['id']}", params: payload
```

Comment: You should have an [application level validation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence) which should prevent the driver error from occuring in the first place. Your test should not be catching `PG::NotNullViolation`. The database level not null constraint is really just there to protect the integrity of your data when its inserted in way that bipasses the validations.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Section` model (probably at `app/models/section.rb`. Add a `belongs_to` and a validation:

```rb
class Section < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :type

  validates :by_team, presence: true
end
```